# Calculating where to place one arbitrary 2d shape in another?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, polygon, bin-packing

How do I calculate how to fit shape A into shape B? Are there some algorithms I could look up? Neither shape should scale.

[image]

This is pretty close except he doesn't specify what routines he's using:
[Find maximum area polygon inscribed in larger polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359831/find-maximum-area-polygon-inscribed-in-larger-polygon)

The actual use case is fitting a building footprint into an arbitrary area. It's for RTS AI where they need to find a location to place a building.

Comment: Can you scale B? 
Anyhow, it's NP in the end. Think of arbitrary complex A and B. It bin packing knapsack etc...

Comment: There's a lot of fun algorithms for good approximations though.. maybe describe your real use case closer.